# Is it correct to use “or” in place of “and/or”?

Tags: conjunctions, connotation, semantics, logic, disjunction

Consider the following sentence:

> A project is a large and/or complex undertaking.

To me, the expression “and/or” seems redundant since in formal logic “or” implies “and”:

```
 Table: truth table for            Table: truth table for            Table: truth table for
 logical OR (i.e. ∨).              logical AND (i.e. ∧).             exclusive OR (i.e. ⊕).

 -----------------------           -----------------------           -----------------------
    A       B     A ∨ B               A       B     A ∧ B               A       B     A ⊕ B
 ------- ------- -------           ------- ------- -------           ------- ------- -------
    F       F       F                 F       F       F                 F       F       F
    F       T       T                 F       T       F                 F       T       T
    T       F       T                 T       F       F                 T       F       T
    T       T       T                 T       T       T                 T       T       F
 -----------------------           -----------------------           -----------------------
```

Hence, I simply use “or” in place of “and/or”:

> A project is a large or complex undertaking.

To me this implies that a project is:

1. Either large.
2. Or complex.
3. Or both.

Am I correct?

On the other hand, using “either/or” seems to imply exclusive “or”:

> A project is either a large or a complex undertaking.

This implies that a project is:

1. Either large.
2. Or complex.
3. But not both.

If using “or” does imply “either/or/both”, then I believe that it's incorrect to use “and/or” at all. Am I correct in assuming so?

Comment: "Or" may include _and_ in formal logic, but in natural language, it means **XOR**. Do not try out people's patience interpreting natural language as formal logic. When asked if you want cream or sugar with your coffee, or whether the new child is a boy or a girl, do **not** reply **yes**.

Comment: @oerkelens So, do you want cream and/or sugar with your coffee?

Comment: @MadSorcerer: No :) I drink straight.

Comment: Is it a boy xor a girl?

Comment: @oerkelens Not exactly. In natural language, it means "exactly one of the choices provided", which only means "xor" when there are two choices provided. In response to "You can have an apple, a banana, or an orange.", "Okay, I'll have all three please." is probably not acceptable, even though true xor true xor true is true.

Comment: @hvd: yes, I was only talking about binary operations. In the case of three choices, it acts as a _trinary_ xor, in which case XOR(true, true, true) = false.

Comment: **The English language is not a tool for expressing syllogisms.**     (Or other logical statements). You can just about do it if you really try, just as you can drive screws with a hammer. But objecting that English doesn't obey the rules of logic is beside the point - that's not what English is for.

Comment: @oerkelens Ah, we're both half right. See for example [Wolfram](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/XOR.html) where it lists a truth table for what it calls "ternary xor": it gives a result of true if all of the inputs are true. But I can also find references to support your calling it "xor", such as [this paper](http://www.sfu.ca/~jeffpell/papers/IGPLTernaryExclOr.pdf). It seems clear enough that we do mean the same thing about the English meaning of "a, b or c" though, so it's probably okay.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *or* of English is not equivalent to the *or* of formal logic. In many cases, English *or* actually means the *exclusive or* of logic. For instance, if you say:

> Turn left or right at the intersection.

it’s exclusive, because it’s not possible to do both. Or you might ask:

> Are you having a boy or a girl?

(Although a logician having fraternal twins might humorously answer “yes”.)

As a result, the phrase *and/or* is used to make it clear that the inclusive sense is intended.

However, there are many contexts where it’s clear that only the inclusive meaning makes sense. In this case, you can simply say *or* and be understood. Your example sentence is such a case -- no one would assume that *large* and *complex* are mutually exclusive (in fact, one often implies the other). Another example is:

> He can’t read or write.

This last sentence also obeys de Morgan’s Law, as it means the same thing as

> He can’t read and he can’t write.

Comment: I could either take your word for it or ask for a citation.

Comment: I've given examples.

Comment: He will probably have to cite all of his English teachers who taught him in all the schools he studied.

Comment: I was originally going to cite the fact that I've been speaking the language for 50+ years, as well as programming for 35 of them, so I have experience with both uses of OR.

Comment: "He can't read or write." I'd have written that as "He can neither read nor write", which happens to match NOR as well.

Comment: The logician would answer "yes" to "Are you having a boy or a girl?" without needing twins. "I am having a child. If that child is a boy, I am having a boy or a girl. If that child is a girl, I am having a boy or a girl.  Therefore, yes, I am having a boy or a girl."

Comment: @AaditMShah you'd likely not find a citation, as this would come under assumed knowledge among English native speakers. Think of it as AND/XOR not and/or. As this answer states, OR in natural English usage is almost always akin to XOR. And/or is actually the closest translation of OR.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the confusion, this would be my answer, and yes, it seems to contradict the accepted answer. So be it. ;-)

**Yes, most of the time you should in fact write *or* instead of *and/or*.**

In cases where you do not want the and/or meaning of inclusive OR, make that clear explicitly: *A or B,* ***but not both***.

With no additional context or qualification, *or* is ambiguous in English. Given that, the default understanding by a listener is (as is usual in interpretation) to allow the greatest number of possible interpretations.

In other words, someone hearing *or* and not knowing which meaning is meant will entertain **all** possibilities that make sense in the given context.

To narrow things down, you provide additional context, or you make clear (explicitly) that you mean exclusive OR, not inclusive OR.

Examples that involve phrases such as "*boy or girl*" provide such context (hermaphrodites are typically ignored), so it is unnecessary to add "*but not both*".  (Such examples really do not help to elucidate this question, without additional explanation.)

Why should you write *or* instead of *and/or*? **Because that's the way we speak.** English speakers already listen to *or* in the way I described above.  Using *and/or* is stilted; it sounds artificial and draws attention unnecessarily to something unimportant. (Or if used to for an important distinction then it is too weak - make the distinction explicit.)

Worse: using *and/or* can actually confuse readers, in part because once you start using it a reader will expect you to use it consistently, and you won't! Or if you do somehow use it consistently, the result will be almost unreadable (*or* is too common a word).

Keep it simple: write the way English speakers speak. That lets you take advantage of the way they understand, without making them jump through additional hoops requiring special parsing of your language.

Answer (score 2):

I'm surprised that no one has cited Strunk and White -- consummate authorities on English usage -- who settled this issue long ago. From Strunk and White, *The Elements of Style*, Fourth Edition, pg. 40:

> **And/or**. A device, or shortcut, that damages a sentence and often leads to confusion or ambiguity.

In place of:

> ... would an honor system successfully cut down on the amount of **stealing and/or cheating**

White says to write instead:

> ... would an honor system successfully cut down on the amount of **stealing or cheating or both**.

So there you have it. OR, AND, and XOR all accounted for in the most elegant way possible.